# Terminology: $n$-th root of a degree-$n$ homogeneous polynomial is not degree-1 homogeneous?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, terminology

Suppose that $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m)$ is a degree $n$ homogeneous polynomial in $m$ variables. Then, at least according to [the Wikipedia page on homogeneous polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Homogeneous_polynomials), we can look at the function $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m)^{1/n}$ to get a homogeneous function of degree 1.

The main issue with this is, at least on Wikipedia, homogeneous polynomials require $f(kx_1, kx_2, ..., kx_m) = k^n f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m)$ for **all** real numbers $k$, even negative $k$.

This would seem to break the above assertion for even-degree polynomials, such as

$$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2$$

where it is easy to see that

$$f(-1 \cdot x_1, -1 \cdot x_2)^{1/2} = ((-1) \cdot x_1 \cdot (-1) \cdot x_2)^{1/2} = (x_1x_2)^{1/2} \neq -(x_1x_2)^{1/2}$$

However, the initial assertion is true if we instead look only at non-negative $k$. It is also true if you More subtly, there is probably something you can do with the Riemann surface associated to $f(z) = z^{1/2}$, so I am mainly wondering what the "correct" definition is.

**My question**: can someone clarify the canonical definition of a homogeneous function, and is the initial assertion true?

Comment: For $k=-1$, how do you interpret $k^{1/2}$ as real number?

Comment: Right, that's basically why the original assertion doesn't seem to be true without some qualification. So what is the basic definition in standard terminology?

Comment: The standard definition of homogenous polynomial is the one you wrote (and also the one in the wikipedia) and doesn't cause any problems since $(-1)^d$ is well-defined as real number for all $d$. However, the "taking root" operation you mentioned doesn't seem to be well-defined over $\mathbb R$. In fact, eben over an algebraically closed field such as $\mathbb C$, this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Hm, OK. Is there a standard, "related" definition which makes the original claim true? I see there's the notion of an "absolutely homogeneous" function...

Comment: The definition of homogenous function is made in order to study their zero-sets as subsets of projective space (which, as one can argue, is the natural space for studying these zero-sets). The definition $f(\lambda z)=\lambda^d f(z)$ just tells you that the class of a point $z$ in $k^n$ is mapped to the class of the point $f(z)$ in $k^n$, i.e. that you have a well-defined function on $\mathbb P^n_k$. (...)

Comment: (...) To come back to your question, even over algebraically closed fields you have the issue that a term like $z^{1/k}$ has no unique meaning and I do not know if issues can be solved by passing to the Riemann surface of such a function but I think its a very strange way of considering this problem. This is because on the one hand you have projective space over $k$ where your function lives and on the other hand you construct some Riemann surface which can be very different from your projective space. Anyway, you do not get a homogenous polynomial of degree one with the standard definition.